# Is it safe to compare enum objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have a module that defines an enum this way:

```
import enum
class MyEnum(enum.IntEnum):
  FIRST = 1
  SECOND = 2
```

and a function that returns:

```
def return_a_value():
  my_enum = MyEnum(2)
  return my_enum
```

When comparing the return value, is it safe to write code like this:

```
if return_a_value() == MyEnum.SECOND:
```

or am I supposed to access the `value` field instead for comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *safe-enough*, although, someone can always implement an object's `__eq__` method to return *whatever they want*.

But given that `enum`'s are singletons, you can actually use `is`  safely:

```
if return_a_value() is MyEnum.SECOND:
```